# How to groupby a column with multiple column values convert into multiple columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I have a dataframe which looks like this

| index | School | id | Subjects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sch1 | 123 | English maths social |
| 2 | Sch67 | 789 | English maths science |
| 3 | Sch12 | 123 | English Telugu Hindi |

But I want to convert it into below dataframe with each subject count  and groupby id

| id | English | Telugu | maths | Hindi | science | social |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 789 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I tried with group by for each column and it didnt work for me

I want the code to be dynamic because the input is a large dataframe and I have taken only a chunk of df

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to split the subject strings into separate columns, then run `pd.get_dummies` on these columns, then group by id and sum:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df1['Subjects'].str.split(expand=True))

# print(dummies):
#    0_English  1_Telugu  1_maths  2_Hindi  2_science  2_social
# 0          1         0        1        0          0         1
# 1          1         0        1        0          1         0
# 2          1         1        0        1          0         0

# Delete the prepended integers and underscores from column names
dummies.columns = [c.split('_')[1] for c in dummies.columns]

# Bring in the id of each row
dummies['id'] = df1['id']

dummies.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
```

Result:

| id | English | Telugu | maths | Hindi | science | social |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 789 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |